# Need assistance with VBA code Converting CSV > XLS

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for assistance with the code below. Basically what I am trying to do is from my most recent downloads folder import most recent CSV into excel and format columns as TEXT to alleviate the issue of truncating 0. The issue with the code below is that it applies TEXT format to all columns. Is there any way to search and find specific headers and only convert columns when header "contains or is named" something? Really we want to try and keep all other values as number, currency, etc. I would appreciate any help. The code below is a combination of a few different codes I was able to find online and put together. Thanks all!

```
Sub recentFileSpecificFolder()

 Dim myFile As String, myRecentFile As String, myMostRecentFile As String, FinalFile As String
 Dim recentDate As Date
 Dim myDirectory As String
 myDirectory = "File Directory Here"
 Dim fileExtension As String
 fileExtension = "*.csv"

 If Right(midirectory, 1) <> "\" Then myDirectory = myDirectory & "\"

 myFile = Dir(myDirectory & fileExtension)

 If myFile <> "" Then
     myRecentFile = myFile
     recentDate = FileDateTime(myDirectory & myFile)
 Do While myFile <> ""
     If FileDateTime(myDirectory & myFile) > recentDate Then
     myRecentFile = myFile
     recentDate = FileDateTime(myDirectory & myFile)
 End If
 myFile = Dir
 Loop
 End If
 myMostRecentFile = myRecentFile
   
 FinalFile = myDirectory & myMostRecentFile
 
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FinalFile, Destination:=Range("A1"))
 
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .RefreshPeriod = False
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 65001
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = _
            **Array(xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat)**
            .Refresh
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh

        End With
        
        Dim wb_connection As WorkbookConnection
        For Each wb_connection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        If InStr(file_name, wb_connection.Name) > 0 Then
        End If
        Next wb_connection
            
       MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```